# Fast extraction of earliest NYSE listing date with FinancialData

Tags: finance

I would like to know the fastest way to find the earliest listing date of a given symbol on the New York Stock Exchange - for example,

```
FinancialData["AAPL", All][[1,1]]
```

returns

```
{1980,12,12}
```

Which is correct, since AAPL was first listed on the NYSE on 1980/12/12.

This method is extremely slow, however, given one has to get the entire time series for a company in order to access its first element. Is there a faster way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
FinancialData["AAPL", "IPODate"]
```

> {1980, 12, 12}

```
FinancialData["GE", "IPODate"]
```

> {1892, 6, 23}

Comment: Thanks! Is there a general way to do this for all financial time series given by Mathematica, rather than just stocks?

The above solution works for "AAPL", but returns `Missing[NotAvailable]` on an ETF such as AAXJ.

Comment: @BrianBurns, I don't know a general way that for works for all `FinancialData` seris.